# how to use gevent not to exceed http connection pool?

Tags: gevent

I want to call function to crawl data on the web using HTTP requests but it is too slow to call each function sequentially so that I found out about gevent library in python to make the logic run parallelly. But the source code is like the following. if content is big, I got error like the following. How can I set for the gevent to call my functions within the limited resource?

```
    monkey.patch_all()
    threads = [gevent.spawn(yahoo.download_csv, tkr) for tkr in content]
    gevent.joinall(threads)
```

The error is..

```
    File "D:\dev\Python36-64\lib\ssl.py", line 465, in options
      super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
    [Previous line repeated 318 more times]
  RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

The yahoo.download_csv is the function to crawl data using http requests and return the crawled data based on the ticker.

Comment: What version of gevent are you using? With Python 3.6, you must have at least gevent 1.2. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/903 Also, are you monkey-patching *first* before importing anything else? That's important. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016